# Apache redirect seems to ignore ServerName

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, redirect

I have a couple virtual host files. The first one redirects all traffic for http://www.mysite.com to the https version:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.mysite.com
   Redirect permanent / https://www.mysite.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerName www.mysite.com
   # additional configuration
</VirtualHost>
```

The second defines a VirtualDocumentRoot so that sites in directories such as /var/www/www.othersite.com will be served.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%0
    VirtualScriptAlias  /var/www/%0/cgi-bin/
</VirtualHost>
```

I also have NameVirtualHost definitions in the ports.conf file (in case that is helpful):

```
NameVirtualHost *:443
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

The problem is that all traffic seems to be redirected to https://www.mysite.com. I would expect that the `ServerName www.mysite.com` line in the first virtual host file would only match www.mysite.com so that visiting http://www.othersite.com would serve content from /var/www/www.othersite.com. When I comment out the entire port 80 VirtualHost definition from the first file, http://www.othersite.com loads as expected. Am I missing something here? How do I only redirect http to https for www.mysite.com?

**Edit:**

The reason I can't put the ServerName as http://www.othersite.com in the second VirtualHost definition is that there are multiple sites in /var/www that also need to be served.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add `ServerName www.othersite.com` directive to the second virtual host?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This would work great, except that there are multiple sites that need to be served via the second VirtualHost file. I edited my question to reflect this.

Comment: Well, if you have multiple sites you will need multiple virtual hosts each one with a server name, isn't it?

Comment: That is actually something that you can solve with VirtualDocumentRoot  in one VirtualHost configuration. VirtualDocumentRoot will (if I understand it correctly) lookup the directory on the server based on the domain that is requested by the client. I inherited a server that hosted many domains (with document roots such as /var/www/www.othersite.com and /var/www/mydomain.com), only one of which needed to be protected by https, so when I attempted to add the VirtualHost configuration (the first one from my question) I ran into this problem.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging, I found [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/373673), which led me to add the following to my second VirtualHost definition:

```
ServerName host
ServerAlias *
```

A couple other answers that were very helpful:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/550581
- https://serverfault.com/a/463879/221978